# How to filter Django annotations on reverse foreign key fields

Tags: django, django-aggregation

I am trying to get a count of all related models with a particular field value.

Here is some code...

**models.py:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
  BAD = "BAD"
  MEH = "MEH"
  GOOD = "GOOD"
  GREAT = "GREAT"
  REVIEW_CHOICES = (
    (BAD, BAD.title()),
    (MEH, MEH.title()),
    (GOOD, GOOD.title()),
    (GREAT, GREAT.title()),
  )
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  review = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=REVIEW_CHOICES)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
```

Suppose I want to list the number of each type of reviews for each author.

I have tried:

```
Authors.object.annotate(n_good_books=Count("books")).filter(books__review="GOOD").values("name", "n_good_books")
```

I have also tried:

```
Authors.object.annotate(n_good_books=Count("books", filter=Q(books_review="GOOD"))).values("name", "n_good_books")
```

But neither of these works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - 1.11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `.filter(..)` *before* the `.annotate(..)`, so:

```
Authors.object.filter(
    books__review="GOOD"  # before the annotate
).annotate(
    n_good_books=Count("books")
)
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` of `Author`s, where each `Author` has an extra attribute `.n_good_books` that contains the number of good `Book`s. The opposite means that you *only* will retrieve `Author`s for which *at least* one related `Book` has had a good review. As is [specified in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#filter-and-exclude):

> When **used with an `annotate()` clause**, a filter has the effect of
>   **constraining the objects for which an annotation is calculated**. For example, you can generate an annotated list of all books that have
>   a title starting with "Django" using the query:
>
> ```
> >>> from django.db.models import Count, Avg
> >>> Book.objects.filter(name__startswith="Django").annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))
> ```
>
> (..)
>
> **Annotated values can also be filtered**. The alias for the annotation can be used in `filter()` and `exclude()` clauses in the
>   same way as any other model field.
>
> For example, to generate a list of books that have more than one
>   author, you can issue the query:
>
> ```
> >>> Book.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors')).filter(num_authors__gt=1)
> ```
>
> This query generates an annotated result set, and then generates a
>   filter based upon that annotation.

The `Count(..., filter=Q(..))` approach only works since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), so in [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11) this will *not* work.

Comment: Is there a way to do add annotations for _each_ book review type all at once, so I would wind up w/ a count for "n_good_books", "n_bad_books", "n_great_books", etc.?

Comment: @trubliphone: yes but it is very inelegant. I would advice to upgrade to Django-2.0, such that you can make use of the `Count(..,filter=...)` approach.

Answer (score 1):

@willem-van-onsem has the correct answer to the question I asked.

*However*, if I wanted to get a count for all book types at once, I could do something like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, IntegerField

Authors.object.annotate(
  n_bad_books=Count(Case(When(books__review="BAD", then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
  n_meh_books=Count(Case(When(books__review="MEH", then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
  n_good_books=Count(Case(When(books__review="GOOD", then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
  n_great_books=Count(Case(When(books__review="GREAT", then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
)
```

And he's right, it is very inelegant.